# Play application.conf - test configs

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

In Play *application.conf* I have *default* values, `%test`, `%stage` and `%prod` values:

```
%stage.application.mode=prod
%prod.application.mode=prod
%test.application.mode=test

#default values
property=someValue

%test.property=testValue

%stage.property=stageValue

%prod.property=prodValue
```

I cannot change these because they're used when the app is deployed to the respective environments.

However, I need to be able to start Play in test mode for unit testing on a local machine with different settings than what's in %test.

Is there a way of adding another test config, say `%unittest` and start Play in test mode (*play test*) using these configs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually works the other way around:

You define

`%test-unit.application.mode=dev`

**Important:** The prefix has to be `test-`

and set values like

`%test-unit.property=testValue`

finally, you need to set the "id" of your Play server on the command line:

`$ play id`

which, for this example would be `test-unit`.

Reference: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.5/guide11

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why I cannot use `%test.application.mode=test` and start play in test mode (`play test`)? I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class play.Play$Mode.TEST`.

Comment: There's only 2 modes, `dev` and `prod`. `dev` is the mode for testing). I've amended the answer to reflect that.

Comment: That's right! Although it seems that if I have `%unittest.application.mode=dev` and `%test.application.mode=dev`, I set _play id_ to _unittest_ and start `play test`, it loads the `%test` configs not the `%unittest`.

Comment: I was going by the documentation. Now having looked at the source, it turns out you have to use the special prefix `test-` if you're running `test`. I've tested it out with the `http.port` property, and it works this way. The answer is updated (again).